# Is it possible to override the width and height of the <object> in this iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

In the iframe below, you will see an `<object>` at the bottom with the id of #videoPlayerSWF (I included the rest of the iframe code just in case)

Via JS, I have tried selecting it and manipulating the width and height of this element that is being set by the iframe's javascript to match the width and height of the windows.

Below is my failed JS attempt. No matter what, I cannot override the values of #videoPlayerSWF

```
window.onload = function(){
   document.getElementById("videoPlayerSWF").height='100%';
   document.getElementById("videoPlayerSWF").width='100%';
}
```

What's a good way to test if it is even possible at all to override it?

```
<iframe id="musicVideo" width="100%" height="100%" type="text/html" src="http://cache.vevo.com/m/html/embed.html?video=GBA320903400" frameborder="0">


    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
            <title>VEVO EMBED IFRAME</title>
            <script src="http://cache.vevo.com/a/js/lib/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cache.vevo.com/m/js/embed.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cache.vevo.com/m/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://adm.fwmrm.net/p/Vevo_chromeless_wrapper/AdManager.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://livepassdl.conviva.com/ver/2.50.0.56856/LivePass.js?customerId=c3.Vevo"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () { selectEmbed(); });
            </script>
            <style type="text/css">

                #videoPlayerHTML5, #wrapper, #playerHTML5, #playerSWF
                {
                    width:100%;
                    height:100%;
                    margin:0px;
                    padding:0;
                    background-color:#000000;
                }

                html
                {
                    width:100%;
                    height:100%;
                    overflow:hidden;
                }

                body
                {
                    height:100%;
                    margin:0px;
                    padding:0;
                }

                #video_overlay {
                    position:absolute;
                    z-index:19790119;
                    opacity:0.4;
                        filter:alpha(opacity=40);
                        top: 20px;
                        right: 20px;
                }

            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                function selectEmbed() {
                    switch (getParameter("forceSelect")) {
                        case "0":
                            $("#playerHTML5").hide();
                            embedSwf(); break;
                        case "1":
                            $("#playerSWF").hide();
                            initializeHTML5(); break;
                        default:
                            embedDynamicVideo(); break;
                    }
                }

                function embedDynamicVideo() {
                    var video = getParameter("video");
                    var playlist = getParameter("playlist") || false;
                    var autoplay = getParameter("autoplay") || "0";
                    var playerType = getParameter("playerType") || "embedded";
                    var cultureName = getParameter("cultureName") || "en_us";
                    var cultureIsRTL = getParameter("cultureIsRTL") || "False";
                    var embed = getParameter("embed");
                    var sbId = getParameter("sbId") || "C188A3CA-3593-453A-B995-394B7A7E5332";
                    var siteSection = getParameter("siteSection") || "vevo_player_embedded";

                    vevoEmbed.embedDynamicVideo(video, siteSection, sbId, $("#playerHTML5"), $("#videoPlayerHTML5"), "playerSWF", "videoPlayerSWF", $("#playerSWF").width(), $("#playerSWF").height());
                }

                function initializeHTML5() {
                    var sbId = getParameter("sbId") || "C188A3CA-3593-453A-B995-394B7A7E5332";
                    var video = getParameter("video");
                    var autoplay = getParameter("autoplay") || "0";
                    var addAuto = (autoplay == "1");

                    if (addAuto) {
                        $('videoPlayerHTML5').attr('autoPlay', true);
                    }
                    var siteSection = getParameter("siteSection") || "vevo_player_embedded";
                    vevoEmbed.embedVevoVideo(video, siteSection, sbId, $('#playerHTML5'), $('#videoPlayerHTML5'));
                }

                function getParameter(sParam) {
                    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
                    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
                    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
                        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
                        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
                            return sParameterName[1];
                        }
                    }
                }

                function embedSwf() {

                    var video = getParameter("video");
                    var playlist = getParameter("playlist") || false;
                    var autoplay = getParameter("autoplay") || "0";
                    var playerType = getParameter("playerType") || "embedded";
                    var cultureName = getParameter("cultureName") || "en_us";
                    var cultureIsRTL = getParameter("cultureIsRTL") || "False";
                    var embed = getParameter("embed");
                    var sbId = getParameter("sbId") || "C188A3CA-3593-453A-B995-394B7A7E5332";
                    var siteSection = getParameter("siteSection") || "vevo_player_embedded";


                    var environment = getParameter("branch");
                    var baseurl = ""
                    switch (environment) {
                        case 'local': baseurl = "http://localhost:3086"; break;
                        case 'staging': baseurl = "http://stg-videoplayer.vevo.com"; break;
                        default: baseurl = "http://videoplayer.vevo.com"; break;
                    }

                    swfobject.embedSWF(baseurl + "/embed/embedded", "playerSWF", "100%", "100%", "10.1.53", false, { /*flashvars*/
                        'playerType': playerType,
                        'videoId': video,
                        'playlist': playlist,
                        'enableDomScan': 'false',
                        'siteSection': siteSection,
                        'autoplay': autoplay,
                        'cc': "US",
                        'cultureName': cultureName,
                        'cultureIsRTL': cultureIsRTL,
                        'embed': embed,
                        'endScreen': 'play',
                        'sbId': sbId
                    }, { /*params*/
                        bgcolor: "#000000",
                        allowFullScreen: "true",
                        allowScriptAccess: "always",
                        wmode: "transparent"
                    }, { /*attributes*/
                        id: "videoPlayerSWF"
                    });
                }
            </script>
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="videoPlayerSWF" data="http://videoplayer.vevo.com/embed/embedded" width="924" height="835"><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"><param name="wmode" value="transparent"><param name="flashvars" value="playerType=embedded&amp;videoId=GBA320903400&amp;playlist=false&amp;enableDomScan=false&amp;siteSection=vevo_player_embedded&amp;autoplay=0&amp;cc=US&amp;cultureName=en_us&amp;cultureIsRTL=False&amp;embed=&amp;endScreen=play&amp;sbId=C188A3CA-3593-453A-B995-394B7A7E5332"></object>
            <div id="playerHTML5" style="display: none;">
                <div id="video_overlay">
                    <img src="http://stg-m.vevo.com/m/img/logo/vevo_logo_white.png">
                </div>
                <video id="videoPlayerHTML5"></video>
            </div>


        </body></html>
    </iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot manipulate or target iframe content via javascript that origins from another domain (in this case vevo.com).

But even if you could, you must target the appropriate `window` object (the iframe), and not the global window that the parent site runs in:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('musicVideo');
var iframe_window = iframe.contentWindow;
iframe_window.document.getElementById("videoPlayerSWF").height='100%';
// etc
```

But as said, this will not work if the iframe src is on another domain.